# EditText in custom layout listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I'm developing an app that has a custom layout list of items.I have implemented the Product class with all the method it needs, I've started writing the CustomAdapter class for my ArrayList. Each row contains 4 EditText boxes, 2 inputType="number" and 2 regular ones, and 2 ImageViews. Other functionalities (image onclick, removing items from list, etc. work) however when I focus on an EditText the adapter automatically refreshes (or so I think) the list elements and I cannot write anything in the text boxes. The strange thing is that the number boxes work, and they are done the same. I've read somewhere that there is an issue with EditTexts in ListViews, but I find it hard to believe that I can't implement such a thing in my app.

Here is my custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements OnClickListener {

         /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
         private Activity activity;
         private ArrayList data;
         private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
         public Resources res;
         Product tempValues=null;
         int i=0;
         String TAG = "CustomAdapter"; 

         public int currentItem = 0;

         /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
         public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

                /********** Take passed values **********/
                 activity = a;
                 data=d;
                 res = resLocal;

                 /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
                  inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         }

         /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
         public int getCount() {

             if(data.size()<=0)
                 return 1;
             return data.size();
         }

         public Object getItem(int position) {
             return position;
         }

         public long getItemId(int position) {
             return position;
         }

         /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
         public static class ViewHolder{ 
             public EditText productET;
             public EditText priceET;
             public EditText obsET;
             public EditText quantET;
             public ImageView checked;
             public ImageView unchecked;
             public ImageView delete;

         }

         /****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
         public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

             View vi = convertView;
             final ViewHolder holder;

             if(convertView==null){

                 /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
                 vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row3, null); 
                 /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

                 holder = new ViewHolder();
                 holder.productET = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.product);
                 holder.priceET = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.price);
                 holder.obsET = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.obs);
                 holder.quantET = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                 holder.checked = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.checked);
                 holder.unchecked = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.unchecked);
                 holder.delete = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.delete);

                /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                 vi.setTag( holder );
             }
             else {
                 holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
             }
             if(data.size()<=0)
             {


             }
             else
             {
                 /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
                 tempValues=null;
                 tempValues = ( Product ) data.get( position );

                 /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

                  holder.productET.setText( tempValues.getName() );
                  holder.priceET.setText( String.valueOf(tempValues.getPrice()) );
                  holder.obsET.setText( tempValues.getInfo() );
                  holder.quantET.setText( String.valueOf(tempValues.getQuntity()) );
                  holder.checked.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.mit.shoppinglist:drawable/checked",null,null));
                  holder.unchecked.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.mit.shoppinglist:drawable/unchecked",null,null));
                  holder.delete.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.mit.shoppinglist:drawable/delete",null,null));

                  /**************/
                  if(tempValues.getStatus()){
                    holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.unchecked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  }
                  else {
                        holder.checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.unchecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }

                  /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/

                  holder.checked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            holder.checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.unchecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
                            sct.changeStatus(position, false);
                    }
                });
                  holder.unchecked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.unchecked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
                        sct.changeStatus(position, true);
                    }
                });
                  holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
                        sct.removeItem(position);
                    }
                });
                  vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));
             }
             return vi;
         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                 Log.v(TAG, "=====Row button clicked=====");
         }

         /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
         private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
             private int mPosition;

             OnItemClickListener(int position){
                  mPosition = position;
                  currentItem = position;
             }

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {


               MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;

              /****  Call  onItemClick Method inside CustomListViewAndroidExample Class ( See Below )****/

                 sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
             }               
         }   
     }
```

and in my MainClass

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)    
    CustomListView = this;
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productList);
    Resources res = getResources();
    adapter=new CustomAdapter( CustomListView, al,res );
    lv.setAdapter( adapter );
    produs = new Product("bread", "just white bread", 0, 2, false);
    al.add(produs);
    produs = new Product("weat bread", "can be white", 0, 5, true);
    al.add(produs);
    produs = new Product("potatoes", "fresh", 0, 2, true);
    al.add(produs);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    public void removeItem(int poz) {
        al.remove(poz);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void changeStatus(int poz, Boolean status) {
        al.get(poz).setStatus(status);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can do it, but it is generally considered not good practice to have focusables in listview. ListView reuses cells, so if you scroll down, it can cause "jumping" of focus.

Comment: My issue is that I cannot edit all of those text boxes and it calls the OnItemClickListener(int position){} method about 12 times, for a 3 item list, whenever I focus an EditText box

Comment: if there are not too much items for the listview, I suggest just inflating items into linear layout and avoid using Listview.

Comment: the list is endless, it depends on the user, however I'll also need to remove items from it. I'm not sure that just setting the visibility to GONE will do the job in aligning the other views